# How do YOU use Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, new-users, usability, community

I've found it more difficult than I expected to get drawn into Stack Overflow. It works great for when I have a question - I can almost always find the answer or ask new questions and quickly get an answer. But as far as being able to find other questions that interest me or that I can contribute to, I haven't really settled into a way to participate.

What features and pages of the site do you use to engage in the community?

Comment: Haven't I seen this question before?

Comment: Maybe not, or at least not exactly.

Comment: feel free to point me in the direction of relevant questions :)

Comment: I also have that feeling, mmyers

Comment: I use my own frontend and auto-watch the top active questions of multiple family sites. This is how I found this question :)

Comment: Then your frontend is not very smart now, is it?

Comment: @V.V: I guess I should add a filter for ignoring questions with "YOU" written in capital ;)

Comment: I capitalized to emphasize the difference between "How does one use Stack Overflow" in an attempt to avoid answers like TheTXI's. oh well :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use StackOverflow with a PC and an internet browser (preferably Firefox or Chrome), as well as a keyboard (for typing questions, answers, and witty comments) as well as a mouse which aids me in navigating the many areas of the website.

Comment: This answer changed my life.

Comment: for better or for worse?

Comment: For richer or for poorer?

Comment: till death do us part?

Answer (score 17):

Here's my twelve-step guide to using SO:

1. Turn on the computer
2. Wait for it to load
3. Log in
4. Wait for it to load
5. Open up Chrome
6. Click the "Stack Overflow" thumbnail
7. Look at the list of unanswered questions
8. Click a few of them with the middle mouse button if they seem interesting
9. Read them in order. Some will suck, some will be decent; occasionally one has learnable information in it: this is the information that is to be learned!
10. Downvote things that suck, upvote things that rock
11. Complain about the sucky ones with the guys on Google Wave
12. Write a poem to Bill the Lizard in a flag for moderator attention

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: #12: confirm/deny?

Comment: What, no ice-cream?

Comment: @snicker: Any moderator on Meta should be able to confirm unless someone deleted my poem.

Comment: #12: Confirmed.

Comment: You misspelled pi. Or was that intentional?

Comment: lol Google Wave

Comment: @Jeff: I still use it!

Comment: my Stack Overflow account was closed.how can i raise question from it.

Answer (score 4):

Two ways:

- **Casual browsing**: Pick one or two tags (via the '[tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/C#)' tab) and browse them idly, reading those who catch your attention and then contribution should follow naturally
- **Actively checking for tags on which you feel you are an expert on**: Use the '[newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest)' tab on the questions tab filtered by the tags you are knowledgeable on so you can see yet unanswered questions and answer among the first. This way you'll be able to feel more rewarded by answering and getting answers accepted.

Answer (score 4):

My method is to hit "refresh" obsessively until I see a question that I know the answer off the top of my head near the top of the list of new questions, then hope I can answer it faster than everybody else.  Otherwise I look for questions where I can impart my decades of wisdom and cynicism.

On Meta, I wait for Welbog to send me a link to one of his brilliant answers, and then I try to be almost as crazy as him.

Comment: Sounds like you massively messed up your own method on this one, eh?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest starting to make use of the "interesting tags" and maybe the ignore feature and start narrowing the questions down to topics you know or like.

I personaly like to read any topic and like to learn random pointers and advice.  I also favorite stuff I know I will deal with soon or want to look further into.

Comment: This answer did not change my life in any significant way.

Comment: How can you tell?

Answer (score 1):

Since there's an RSS feed for almost everything on S.O., one way of getting better at a particular language/field would be suscribing to questions tagged with that particular interest on our Feed readers.

Answer (score 0):

The most common pattern of use:

- go to google or your browser's search box
- enter a programming question
- read the best sounding reply (quite likely to be on SO)

Comment: Man, who asks questions? That's dumb.