# Too many questions

Tags: feature-request, fun, waffles

I think there are too many questions on StackOverflow. It is just too much for anyone to answer! I mean, I could spend my entire life trying to answer all the questions on StackOverflow.

Just to show an example, this is my daily routine:

- Go on StackOverflow
- Go to Unanswered Questions
- Start from the top and answer each question, even if I  am not familiar with the language, or topic.
- Argue with people for down-voting me. I mean, just because I don't know anything about PHP  doesn't mean I can't answer how to assign a variable! At least I'm putting forth effort.

So far I've only been able to answer 500 questions.

I suggest that we make a change to the Ask a Question page to relieve this burden on the technology community, allowing us all to provide answers to questions that have already been asked. Then, when we have all answered them, we can undo the change and start answering the new questions.

The change is this:

Turn

```
<input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Post Your Question" tabindex="120">
```

into

```
<input id="submit-button" onclick="return false;" type="submit" value="Post Your Question" tabindex="120" >
```

This will stop all questions from being posted, and allow us to catch up with answering questions, even if we are inexperienced with the topic!

It would be even better if the submit button acted like the question was submitted, but simply took them back to the home page.

Please join me in the effort to catch up will all the unanswered questions!

Comment: It is not friday yet.

Comment: You'll have to wait until I've answered all the other questions on meta before I answer this.

Comment: At least 50% aren't worth answering, and could easily be closed under existing SO rules.

Comment: There's a badge for that.

Comment: @voyager - it is currently Friday in about 1/3 of the world (http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/)

Comment: @Dom: San Diego ain't one of them.

Comment: @squillman - excellent point.

Comment: Damn, I wanted to add a nice general `always-something-in-somewhere` tag but it was too many characters.

Comment: @gnovice: always-*-in-* works! except the tag system doesn't like *. :(

Comment: Go Go Start Argue. I think your doing it wrong. ;)

Comment: 4 close votes, yet no downvotes. It's a new record!

Comment: @voy, love your current rep

Comment: @Downvoter: so do I.

Answer (score 6):

You're right, we should delete everything and start over!

But perhaps you are going about things the "wrong" way, and getting intimidated by the size of the task you have taken on... For example, I *never* look at the front page of all questions. Never ever ever. That's way too massive and I'd explode from overload.  Instead, I simply conduct a tag search of the ~30 or so most interesting tags in my "interesting" list, set on auto-refresh every 10 minutes. That contains just three languages, a few tools, and a smattering of general concepts like project-management, code-review, fun, subjective, interview-questions etc. That's plenty for me to absorb each day, and almost all my reputation comes from answers in one tag ([perl]).

The rest of my answer would simply be a reiteration of the points covered in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11511/how-do-you-use-stack-overflow).

Comment: Create a new user called `Æther';DROP Table Questions--`

Comment: Oh yes, they call me little Æther Tables...

Comment: Delete it?  We have to nuke it from orbit.  It is the only way to be sure.

Comment: What about the data dumps? They will still exist on other peoples computer. Clearly we need an EMP bomb for the entire world.