# What tools do you use to answer Stack Overflow (Stack Exchange) questions quickly?

Tags: discussion, tips

How do you discover good/interesting questions quickly and efficiently to answer?

Comment: Not sure what "tools" implies? If it's just about how to find the right questions that you can answer then see [How to find the right questions that I can answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44739/how-to-find-the-right-questions-that-i-can-answer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do YOU use Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11511/how-do-you-use-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSS feeds in conjunction with [Notifixlite](http://notifixlite.appspot.com/) to get IM notifications on feed updates. I usually subscribe to the tag feeds of feeds I like, care about (like RSS :D)

Comment: This has by far been the best way to keep a real time view of stackoverflow.  Nice tip.

Answer (score 7):

I tend to pick categories that I have the most experience in and seek out the newest questions there.  I like to take my time answering, and even then I go back and revise my answer on an average of 3 times just because I want it to be a good answer.

I'm not always the fastest to answer, but that's not what SO is about.  It is about providing the best answer.

Answer (score 6):

The main thing I've done is mark lots of tags as ignored, and hide questions with ignored tags.

Comment: I just discovered the ignore feature a couple weeks ago.

Answer (score 2):

I use [StackGuru](https://stackapps.com/questions/345/stackguru-a-near-realtime-bot-for-all-stackexchange-sites) to store my preferred tags and have the questions delivered to my IM soon as they get posted.

Answer (score 2):

You might check http://stackapps.com to see what apps are of interest.

In particular [the app tag](https://stackapps.com/tags/app) is worth a click.

Answer (score 0):

I often use google to add references to further documentation.